# How to send output of `pv` to python script, and output progress one line at a time?

Tags: bash, python, tar, buffer, pv

I use `tar` to quickly copy thousands of small files which I pipe to `pv` to show the progress and speed of the copying.

```
$ sudo tar c --files-from /tmp/camfilenames | 
  pv --width 40 | 
  sudo tar x -C /home/pi/test
```

...this works perfectly.  Example output:

```
191MiB 0:00:03 [58.1MiB/s] [<=>       ]
```

...in the terminal.  But I want to do something more with this output and I have simple python script `/home/pi/screentest.py`:

```
import sys
print "start"
for line in sys.stdin:
    print "line: " + line
print "end"
```

Test run:

```
$ (   sudo tar c --files-from /tmp/camfilenames | 
      pv --width 40 | 
      sudo tar x -C /home/pi/test   ) | 
   python /home/pi/screentest.py
```

Output:

```
start
191MiB 0:00:03 [55.1MiB/s] [<=>       ]
end
```

I understand that `pv` returns everything in one buffer, so how to force it to return it line by line and flush the buffer every time to output something like:

```
start
line: 0MiB 0:00:00 ...
line: 60MiB 0:00:01 ...
line: 120MiB 0:00:02 ...
line: 191MiB 0:00:03 ...
end
```

Comment: If you like a fast copy, I recommend to use `star -copy`.

Answer (score 1):

`pv` outputs the progress to stderr, so pipe to the python script didn't get anything from `pv`. It printed `end` after `pv`'s output stopped probably because by then the last `tar` had exited, and so the script's stdin had been closed.

You might need something like:

```
( sudo tar c --files-from /tmp/camfilenames | 
  pv --width 40 -f | 
  sudo tar x -C /home/pi/test ) 2>&1 >/dev/null | python /home/pi/screentest.py
```

Where we discard the stdout of the tar pipeline, and instead send stderr to the pythons script. Note that we need to force progress output from `pv` with `-f`, since `pv` won't progress if stderr is not a terminal.

But you might want to look in to `pv`'s `--format` option. You can use something like:

```
sudo tar c --files-from /tmp/camfilenames | 
  pv --width 40 --format $'%b %t\n' | 
  sudo tar x -C /home/pi/test
```

to get similar output.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @muru, I tried you'r solution, but in the meantime I found that main issue is with forcing PV to output new lines instead of just updating constantly one line.

So I wrote this:

`$ tail -f /home/pi/log | pv -f |& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n'`

And It worked, so now question was - how to call my python script to do something with every line - and I found that I can use do-while loop for that:

`$ tail -f /home/pi/log | pv -f |& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | (while read -r LINE; do echo $LINE; done;)`

So having this I just use my python script (little LCD handler) to show PV status on LCD:

`tail -f /home/pi/log | pv -f --width 20 -i 2 |& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | (while read -r LINE; do python /home/pi/screen.py $LINE; done;)`

And I re-introduced my TAR script to copy many small files into it:

`$ (sudo tar c --files-from /tmp/camfilenames | pv -f --width 20 -i 1 | sudo tar x -C /home/pi/test) |& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | (while read -r LINE; do python /home/pi/screen.py $LINE; done;)`

So at the end when I add more parameters to PV, and I made few string replaces before sending PV output to LCD, and I add few break lines I have this:

`cd /home/pi/cam \
&& ( \
    sudo tar c --files-from /tmp/camfilenames \
    | pv -f -s $( \
        du -sb /home/pi/cam \
        | awk '{print $1}' \
    ) --width 64 -i 5 \
    | sudo tar x -C /mnt/usb \
) \
|& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' \
| ( \
    while read -r LINE; \
    do LINE="${LINE// /_}"; \
        LINE="${LINE//_\[/ [}"; \
        LINE="${LINE//\]_/] }"; \
        lcd $LINE; \
    done; \
) \
&& cd /home/pi`

This is how PV output looks on LCD:
[image: This is how PV output looks on LCD]